# How can I get my JSON data to work on my alert call when I click on the button in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to get my JSON data to display the school name, type of degree you get at the school, the semester students currently are enrolled in, and the course they enrolled in the given semester, and also the following: Student's firstname, lastname, and age, but when I click on my button (which is bind to a click event) in my HTML document nothing happens. I have debugged it with the JS bin web developer debugger but it's not helpful because it tells me only one error but the error it tells me about is not something I need to be concerned about. Could any one help me? I have put in a lot of work on this.

```js
function displayMessage(obj)
{ 
    alert(obj.School); 
    alert(obj.Degree);
    alert(obj.Semester);
    alert(obj.Class); 
    
   alert(obj.Students[0].firstname);
   alert(obj.Students[0].lastname);
   alert(obj.Students[0].Age);

         for (var i=0; i < obj.Students.length; i++)
         { 
             var name = obj.Students[i];
       alert("The student's first name is" + " " + name.firstname + " " + name.lastname + " " + name.Age);  
         }
} 

function object1() 
{ 
           return 
           { 

                "School": "Cuyahoga Community College", 
                "Degree": "Associates Degree", 
                "Semester": 2017,
                "Class:" "IT Interactive Web Programming"
                "Students":[
                    { "firstname": "Daron", "lastname": "Seals", "Age": 22 },

                    { "firstname": "Ronny", "lastname": "Miles", "Age": 28 },
                   
                    {"firstname": "Nearson",  "lastname": "Carry", "Age": 23 },
                    
                    {"firstname": "Vearana", "lastname": "Lebarson", "Age": 21 },

                    { "firstname": "Diane", "lastname": "Sivorena", "Age": 35 },
                    
                    { "firstname": "Mark", "lastname": "Tebarassi",  "Age": 76 },

                    { "firstname": "Sara", "lastname": "Cheu",  "Age": 44 },

                    { "firstname": "Vanessa", "lastname": "Hicks", "Age": 18 },

                    { "firstname": "Candy", "lastname": "Heart", "Age": 20 },
 
                    { "firstname": "Susan", "lastname": "Dawson", "Age": 18 }
                  ]
            }; 
 }                 
 
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       $("#btn1").click(function()
       {
          alert(displayMessage())
        });
    });
```

```html
<html> 
<head>
<title>Display of Students at Tri-C</title>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Students Name in the IT 2320 Internet Web Programming Class</h1>
<button id="btn1">Show All Students</button><br>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "I have debugged it with the JS bin web developer debugger but it's not helpful because it tells me only one error but the error it tells me about is not something I need to be concerned about." Um no, the console was telling you exactly what the error was. Don't dismiss console errors so easily. :)

Comment: @ jered you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were few typos in your json object. To be honest I got no clue what did you want to do with this function returning an object. Just store this json inside a variable, e.g. `object1`.

When you call your `displayMessage()` function, you **have to pass** an argument into it, which is actually the json `object1` variable.

`displayMessage(object1);`

And about the `alerts`, their amount is embarassing, maybe simple `console.log` would be better?

The rest seems to be fine, but it would be better to keep `jQuery` away from such a simple app. If you want, I can change the last 4 lines of your code, which are written in `jQuery` into pure js.

```js
var object1 = {School:"Cuyahoga Community College",Degree:"Associates Degree",Semester:2017,Class:"IT Interactive Web Programming",Students:[{firstname:"Daron",lastname:"Seals",Age:22},{firstname:"Ronny",lastname:"Miles",Age:28},{firstname:"Nearson",lastname:"Carry",Age:23},{firstname:"Vearana",lastname:"Lebarson",Age:21},{firstname:"Diane",lastname:"Sivorena",Age:35},{firstname:"Mark",lastname:"Tebarassi",Age:76},{firstname:"Sara",lastname:"Cheu",Age:44},{firstname:"Vanessa",lastname:"Hicks",Age:18},{firstname:"Candy",lastname:"Heart",Age:20},{firstname:"Susan",lastname:"Dawson",Age:18}]};

function displayMessage(obj) {
  alert(obj.School);
  alert(obj.Degree);
  alert(obj.Semester);
  alert(obj.Class);

  alert(obj.Students[0].firstname);
  alert(obj.Students[0].lastname);
  alert(obj.Students[0].Age);

  for (var i = 0; i < obj.Students.length; i++) {
    var name = obj.Students[i];
    console.log("The student's first name is" + " " + name.firstname + " " + name.lastname + " " + name.Age);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    displayMessage(object1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Students Name in the IT 2320 Internet Web Programming Class</h1>
<button id="btn1">Show All Students</button><br>
```

Comment: @ Kind user Do you care to share what you did. I am all about learning from my mistakes!

Comment: @ Kind user Hey thanks so much, but I am just curious why it only goes through one person's information and not the rest of the information?

Comment: Never mind I just have to keep adding alerts to my displayMessage function with different array indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the jQuery before your script.

Comment: @ Anis Alibegić- Is that the reason why my Web Application doesn't work?